# Convergence of Riemann sum to Riemann integral on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, self-learning, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Assume that $h:=h_n>0$ is a sequence satisfying $h\to 0, nh\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Let $K$ be a real function which is nonnegative, symmetric, bounded, Lipschitz continuous and with compact support. Define $K_h(u)=1/hK(u/h)$.

I want to know if for any $x\in[0,1]$

$$\bigg\lvert \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_h(i/n-x)-\int_0^1 K_h(y-x)dy \bigg\rvert\leq \frac{C}{n}?$$
for some constant $C>0$.  I saw results that suggest that this is the case.

**Reference**: [Wand and Jones p. 121](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Kernel_Smoothing.html?id=GTOOi5yE008C&redir_esc=y) (They actually assumed less things than me about the function $K$, except that $K'$ is bounded. But Lipschitz continuity implies $K'$ bounded. This might be crucial) 
I will print the important parts:
[image]
(only the first equality above is of interest here) with

[image]
[image]
[image]

When $l=0$, his result is equivalent to  what I'm asking for. See [Big oh Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).

Comment: This might be easier to read (albeit not necessarily easier to do the calculation) if you just change variables so that you are integrating a single function on $[-x/h,(1-x)/h]$. Then the question is basically about whether the growth of the length of the interval with $n$ damages the convergence. The answer is that it definitely can't, because you are assuming compact support anyway, so you can fall back on the usual estimates for the rectangle rule with a Lipschitz function.

Comment: Note that this step is in fact in the image you posted; the other equalities help you to see the asymptotic result you want.

Comment: @Ian I agree that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n K_h(i/n-x)\to \int_{supp K} K(u)du$. I'm worried about the rate of this convergence. I know the error of the approximation shrinks to zero at order $O(1/(nh))$, as I wrote above. Although, the author obtained a faster rate, i.e., $O(1/n)$. This is not obvious for me. Is it for you? I'm trying to get back and study Riemann approximations a little more, to see if I find something new. This speed of convergence is very important for me to determine if some estimator has good asymptotic properties.

Comment: The point is that you don't want to rely on the Lipschitz constant for $K_h$. So you change variables in the manner they suggested. In the general situation this change of variable doesn't do anything because you stretch the length of the interval and thus the smaller "local" errors are magnified by the longer length of the interval. But in the compactly supported situation you don't have this problem and so you recover the usual estimate for the rectangle rule on a fixed finite interval for a Lipschitz continuous integrand, which has this $O(1/n)$ behavior.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the hints. I'm trying to visualize what is going on, and stop being mechanical. I need a moment to understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Ian Are you trying to tell me that when $n$ is large enough, $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{h}K\big(\frac{y-x}{h}\big)dy-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{h}K\big(\frac{i/n-x}{h}\big)\leq 2[ \int_0^c K(w)dw-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nK\big(\frac{i}{n}\big)]$, given that the support of K is $[-c,c]$ and $K$ symmetric?

Comment: Just write out the change of variable: $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{h} K((y-x)/h) dy = \int_{-x/h}^{(1-x)/h} K(u) du=\int_{-1}^1 K(u) du$ if $n$ (depending on $x$) is large enough and $x \in (0,1)$. Now again for large enough $n$ depending on $x$ you have that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{h} K((i/n-x)/h)=\frac{1}{n_1} \sum_{i=n_1}^{n_2} \frac{1}{h} K((i/n-x)/h)$ where $n_1$ is the smallest $i$ such that $(i/n-x)/h>-x/h$ and $n_2$ is the largest $i$ such that $(i/n-x)/h<(1-x)/h$.

Comment: Now the convergence rate of the rectangle rule will scale like $1/(n_2-n_1)$ once $n$ is large enough that $h_n<\min \{ x,1-x \}$ (which is the only place where the non-uniformity in $x$ comes into play). Work out the scaling of $n_2-n_1$ to finish. It looks like you may have been correct after all that everything scales like $1/(nh)$ but I haven't written out the details.